# How do you deploy new features to a MEAN app on openshift without having downtime?

Tags: openshift, web-deployment, mean

Using openshift to host MEAN app. The app is scaled and I was hoping that when you deploy a new feature, it would deploy to 1 gear keeping the web app live then deploy to second gear. Something like that but the web app goes down while the new feature is being deployed.
I'm aware that hot deployment is coming.

The question is what would be the best way to deploy new features without having any site downtime?
Very new to this kind of thing so apologies if this is really basic!

Comment: Hot deployment isn't working for your app? Check out [enabling hot deployment](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-modifying-applications.html#_enabling_and_disabling_hot_deployment) and [Node.js markers](https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-getting-started.html#markers)

Comment: Don't know how I missed that!! Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future user reference: Check out [enabling hot deployment](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-modifying-applications.html#_enabling_and_disabling_hot_deployment) and [Node.js markers](https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-getting-started.html#markers).